# dojo.date.locale on dojo.mobile 1.8.1 on Worklight 5.0.5.1

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

require(["dojo/date/locale" xxxxxxx) causes scriptError:26. locale.js exists under dojo/date folder but can not be loaded. Is there any limitation to use dojo.date.locale on dojo.mobile 1.8.1-20121024-IBM on Worklight 5.0.5.1 ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with dojox/lang/functional. Although you find all dojo components in your dojo folder, not all of them seem to be copied to the mobile device by default. I added a line like

```
<include name="dojox/lang/functional.js"/>
```

to my build-dojo.xml in the app's root folder and it solved the problem. I think this could work for dojo/date/locale too.